# Embedding a set of inputs from an other entity in a form in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, entities

For a reason I needed to separate some data and now I have three entities:

- Order
- OrderingCompany
- FinalUser

Now Order has some basic data like deliveryPlace etc... and is in One-to-One relationship with OrderingCompany and FinalUser.

Now in one form I want to let the user specify some order data but also all info about ordering company and final user. How can I embed OrderingCompany and FinalUser with many fields because as far as I can see, the entity type lets to choose only one field.

I was thinking about handling the forms manually, but dealing with handleRequest would be a total hell.

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should construct the Order form with two (compound) fields: OrderingCompany and FinalUser.
Both of theses fields can be represented by their own type (but it's not mandatory).

In the example below, I'll <del>go quick and dirty, I'll construct the forms manually.
Nothing forbids you to</del> extract the construction of fields to a separate type.

```php
<?php

class Order extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('orderdata') // orderdata should exist on order entity
            ->add('finalUser', new FinalUserType)
            // same with OrderingCompany
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'order';
    }
}
```

```
class FinalUserType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'FinalUser'));
    }
}
```

### Option 2

There is another possibility: use property paths to directly map a form field to an underlying object of your entity graph (assuming that your graph has correct instances):

```php
<?php

class Order extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('orderdata') // orderdata should exist on order entity
            ->add('finalUserName', 'text', array(
                'property_path' => 'finalUser.name' // $order->getFinalUser()->(get|set)Name() will be called
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```